# database connectivity in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on c# windows project.I am using Microsoft Access database with OleDbConnection connection.My database "email.mdb" is in My document directory and my "email_db.udl" is in "D: drive".This is running well on my computer.But whenever i am making an exe installer file for installment on other Pc this is not working.I am placing "mdb" and "udl" file is in same directory as they are on my PC.I am supposing this ('udl' file) is not connected with my database.
How will i resolve this problem for installation on any windows pc.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the database files in your project's directory (where sln file is) and access them through their bare filenames (without D:...., only filename).
In case of the installation you have to set the installer to put it in the installation folder (where the exe file is)

This is a good way to carry everything in one folder and be organized.

Probably here you have a problem because the "My Document" directory has a different path in every PC.